# Выравнивание значения value по центру в input[type="submit"] в Safari

Tags: css, safari, submit

Верстаю при помощи `flex` и `inline-flex`.
При верстке надпись на кнопках в Safari "прилипает" к левому краю, не знаю, как ее решить.

HTML:

```
<div class="buttonrow">
    <input class="form_submitbutton form_submitbutton_textstyle" type="submit" value="Yes">  
    <div class="form_submitbutton form_submitbutton_textstyle">Cancel</div>
</div>
```

CSS (SCSS):

```
mixin: @mixin boxflex($width, $height, $display, $position, $justify-content, $flex-direction, $flex-wrap, $align-items)
.buttonrow{
    @include boxflex( calc( 100% ), auto, flex, relative, space-around, row, nowrap, center);
}
.form_submitbutton{
    @include boxflex ( 130px, 30px, inline-flex, relative, space-around, row, nowrap, center);  
    background: #3A7DB6;
    color: white; 
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

При этом в Chrome это выглядит нормально
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в Safari так (на масштаб не обращайте внимание)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом, как заметно, в div-е все выглядит как надо. А в input-е - нет.
Добавление `text-align:center` как к родителю, так к элементу - не помогает. Как быть?

Comment: В контексте вашего решения подход неправильный, кнопка должна оставаться кнопкой. flexbox подходит больше для формирования layout страниц, а то, что вы делаете, реализуется более простыми и кроссбраузерными решениями. Пример http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYZpEV

Answer (score 3):

Стили flexbox, разные браузеры понимают только по своим префиксам.
Пример:

```
.page-wrap {
  display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
  display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19 */
  display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: -webkit-flex;     /* NEW - Chrome */
  display: flex;             /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
 }
```

Для автоматизации добавления префиксов посмотрите подходящую для себя библиотеку autoprefixer

https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=autoprefixer